# SFSafariviewcontroller - UIApplication sendEvent not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, uiapplication, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am implementing that app timeout functionality, If user keeping the application in idle for five minutes, the application will get logged out automatically. This concept I did use the `UIApplication` `sendEvent` method.

But, `SFSafariviewcontroller` does not call the `UIApplication` `sendEvent` when the user using the `SFSafariviewcontroller`. So, app getting logged out even though the application used by the user.

Is there any solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to detect activity within an SFSafariViewController.

Reference from the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller?language=objc

> The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are not visible to your app

Instead if you need this functionality you may want to look at WKWebView: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref

> If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet, use the SFSafariViewController class. If your app customizes, **interacts with**, or controls the display of web content, use the WKWebView class.

So my overall recommendation would be to either use WKWebView, or disable the locking strategy while displaying the SafariViewController